# emacs 上の syntax highlight (font?) を保持しながら pdf に出力するには

Tags: emacs

今、 emacs 上で開いているテキストの、
ハイライトされたフォント情報を保持したまま、
pdf に出力したいと考えています。

これを実現する手段はありますでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

htmlfontify-buffer で html を経由すれば、やりたいことが実現できると自己解決しました